# working with namespaced XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

i got an xml structure :

```
<xml>
    <variable>
         <values>
               <enum>
                 <value>2</value>
                 <level>high</level>
               </enum>
               <enum>
                  <value>1</value>
                  <level>medium</level>
               </enum>
               <enum>
                  <value>0</value>
                  <level>low</level>
               </enum>
          </values>
      </variable>
</xml>
```

now, i passed this into a dataProvider:

namespace degro ="http://www.degro.org/td";
use namespace degro;   //this is to bind the namespace

dg.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(xml.variable.value.enum);

and the dataFields of the dg datagrid are value and level

but it wont show when i run the programme..

anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

This is Useful link from Adobe Side [Using XML namespaces](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6c.html)

you may also need to read about [QName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/QName.html) 
 *an objects represent qualified names of XML elements and attributes*

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The XML you posted does not identify a namespace. I'm not an actionscript guy, but in other programming languages if you don't specify the correct namespace the serializer is not going to be able to generate output.

You should probably either update your XML to include a namespace definition (i.e. `<xml xmlns="http://www.degro.org/td"`> or you should set-up your provider to use a blank/empty namespace.

Comment: Hi, i assumed the xml is namespaced by the heading..so, itz there but i just wanted to know how to bind it properly..

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should access a namespaced XML in flex

```
private var degroNS:NameSpace = new NameSpace("http://www.degro.org/td");
//
//
//
dg.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(xml.degroNS::variable.degroNS::value.degroNS::enum);//Assuming xml is the variable name for the xml
```

Comment: is it working fine when you remove the namespace from the dataprovider xml?

Comment: yeas it works perfectly when i remove the namespace..that is why i knew the namespace is the reason for it..and i tried the keyword use namespace degroNs but for now it is not working.

Comment: Just check my code sample.Could not edit this answer.So posted it as a separate answer.Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @henry - You say it's working perfectly when you "remove the namespace". Are you removing the namespace from the XML file or are you removing the namespace from your actionscript code?

Comment: removing the namespace from the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.Check it out and let me know if that helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.degro.org/td");

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                dg.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(dataXML.ns::variable.ns::values.ns::enum);
            }

            private function valueLabelFunction(item:Object,column:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                return item.ns::value+'';
            }

            private function levelLabelFunction(item:Object,column:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                return item.ns::level+'';
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML id="dataXML">
            <xml xmlns="http://www.degro.org/td">
                <variable>
                    <values>
                        <enum>
                            <value>2</value>
                            <level>high</level>
                        </enum>
                        <enum>
                            <value>1</value>
                            <level>medium</level>
                        </enum>
                        <enum>
                            <value>0</value>
                            <level>low</level>
                        </enum>
                    </values>
                </variable>
            </xml>
        </fx:XML>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Value" labelFunction="valueLabelFunction"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Level" labelFunction="levelLabelFunction"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```